# how to replace the MR-16 bulb from this lamp fixture?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, halogen, projector, fixtures

[image]I am wondering how to open this lighting fixture to be able to replace the MR-16 bulb.
The fixture seems smooth with no openings or bolts. It is a bi-pin halogen MR16 bulb. The is a indented ring in front of a glass plate protecting the bulb. Everything seems really air tight with no moving parts.
A real mind boggler!
thank you.
Melvin

Comment: Hi Melvin, it looks like you've accidentally created 2 accounts. See [this article](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for help merging your accounts, this will let you edit your question more easily and accumulate reputation points.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen a few fixtures like that.  See that tabbed ring around the outside of the face of the bulb?  Try compressing it with needle-nose pliers right where the missing tooth is.  It should pull out and then you will be able to pull the bulb out.

Installation is the reverse of removal. :) It should just snap in after the pins of the bulb are seated.

Comment: Hello thanks for the quick responses. Does compressing the rig mean inserting the plyier and pushing out between the open teeth to spread it open flat to the glass? Is it a rubber ring you think? Thanks.

Comment: @melvin your questions about this answer should go here, not as a new answer.  I will answer here as if you asked it here.   I do not think this answer means to push "out".  I think it means in.  Where there is a missing tooth, you push the two adjacent ones toward each other.  That's what the answer says and it makes some sense.  You can use any tool that allows you to do that.  Maybe even your fingernails.  Just try it!

Comment: If it's like the ones I've seen, that ring is a metal spring clip. It uses tension against the outside rim of the light fixture to stay in. The right-angle tabs hold the edge of the bulb in. By grabbing the two teeth surrounding the missing one and pressing them toward each other, you release the tension and then you should be able to work it out toward you. Once that's out of the way, you can pull the bulb with a suction cup or by just working it from the back with something narrow.

Comment: Apparently its general case is an "internal circlip".  If you haven't read enough about them yet look [here](https://www.industrialautomotiveparts.com.au/blog/2021/08/13/circlip-charts) and [here](https://www.engineeringchoice.com/retaining-rings/).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these are push-in, two pin bulbs, you don't need to take it apart.

Use a small suction cup to pull the lamp out from its face.

Use a small wooden stick stuck between the louvers to push the bulb out from behind.

Use a plastic (non conductive) screwdriver stuck under the base of the lamp, through the louvers, to pry it away from the fixture.

Maybe the louvered part of the fixture unscrews from the domed part of each bulb holder.  That would make it easier.

Comment: If the other answer is correct I need to delete this one.  :)

Comment: Usually MR 16 are open that hade a bubble lens so the spring clip is the more likely answer if not screwed together.